# disable mail sending using ini_set in PHP

Tags: php, apache, email, settings, ini

Is it possible to modify a PHP setting value using ini_set such that the mail() function is disabled? Ie. executing mail() would not send mails once a certain ini value is set?

If so, which ini value should I set?

Comment: If you're doing this within your application, why not just skip the mail function in your application?  `ini_set` for `disable_functions` doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by skip the mail function

Comment: In  your code.... `if ($mailEnabled) { mail() }`.  Then just set `$mailEnabled=false` as-needed.

Comment: nah i want to prevent any accidental call to mail() globally for testing purposes

Comment: Well, if you wanted to do it globally you could just change PHP.ini, and then you could use `disable_functions`.  If you don't want to use that, you can load an extension to allow you to replace the function.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php